# How to use BIND command in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bind, embedded-linux

is the command correct?
the PID is showing well, but the files not BIND as requested even running as root.

```
pidof com.abc.im

for i in $(pidof com.abc.im) | awk '{print $1}' | do mount --bind /$i /proc/$i/maps; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `awk` command needs to be inside the command substitution. And you shouldn't pipe to the `do` keyword, there should be a semicolon or newline before it.

```
for i in $(pidof com.abc.im | awk '{print $1}')
do 
    mount --bind /$i /proc/$i/maps
done
```